# Post Filter by Date and time

Tags: posts

I'm trying to get wordpress post by filtering date and time, 
for example get post 01/02/2014 to 07/02/2014.
thanks for the help me.

Comment: So you want to retrieve all posts published between 2 dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `new WP_Query` for this.
Add a new query and pass below argument.

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => '2014-02-01',
            'before'    => '2014-02-07',
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
     ),
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of date related parameters you can specify in a custom query.
You have to use WP_query to fire a new query to get the results.
In this scenario your custom query should contain parameters 'date_query' along with other parameters. I have tried it and It worked for me. Just change your dates.

```
$query_agrs = array(
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'before' => 'January 2nd, 2014',
                'after' => 'December 1st 2013'
                ),
            'inclusive' => true
            ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
$my_query = wp_query($query_agrs);
while($my_query->have_posts()): $my_query->the_post();
the_title();
endwhile;
```

There is an alternative way to define 'before' and 'after' too.

You can also write the before parameter like this:

```
'before' => array('year' => 2014, 'month' => 1, 'day' => 2)
```

similarly with 'after' parameter.